# Box2d Rectangular Body with Rounded Corners

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I have implemented soft body(circle shape) in Box2d and when this soft body collide with the corner of the rectangle box2d object then it lost its circular shape. I think this can be solved by making corners of rectangle rounded or We can implement this rounded corner using soft body concept.

Can anybody guide me in this scenario ?

Comment: why not try out your two thoughts and then come back with a more specific question? SO isn't providing guides, it's about answering specific (preferably narrow scoped) questions, see the FAQ.

Comment: Sorry for not asking specific(narrow scoped) question...And I solved it using physics editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rounded corner I used Physics editor to make rounded corner physics body.You can get physics editor from here:http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor

To add those rounded corner physics in cocos2d iphone , i used GB2ShapeCache to cache those physics shape and then used that from cached memory.

You can get those GB2ShapeCache file bundle from here:http://www.4shared.com/zip/8H6BNDTH/GB2Shape.html

To cached those physics body:
import below file into your code,first import:

```
#import "GB2ShapeCache.h"
```

and then,

```
[[GB2ShapeCache sharedShapeCache] addShapesWithFile:@"rectangleRoundedCornerBody.plist"];
```

Now rounded corner rectangle is in your cache so to use that you can call them using their names like shown in below.

```
[[GB2ShapeCache sharedShapeCache] addFixturesToBody:PhysicsBody forShapeName:@"nameOfRectangleBody"];
```

If any one wants further explanation can comment..